# Is there anyway I can find all tags in Team Server Foundation?

Tags: tfs, devops

We are trying to clean up Team Foundation Server. The problem on hand is that we are using the older version (Not the latest Azure DevOps) and over the period of time we haven't used standard tags. So we have multiple tags for the same thing. I am trying to sort this out. Any help in this is much appreciated folks.

Answer (score 1):

The Tag Manager Extension is probably exactly what you're after. It's as old as TFS 2017, so there must be a version that works with older TFS version

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.TagsManager2